# Open details in row click - kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI web in an ASP.NET MVC4 project.
 
I am trying to create a master/details grids and a detailsTemplate for each. I have some question regarding this situation:
What's the difference between hierarchy and details?
Is it possible to populate the details grid in a separate div on a master row click instead of that little triangle?
 
This code was my starting point : http://jsfiddle.net/WKSkC/2/

```
var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
    },
    pageSize: 6,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true
},
height: 430,
sortable: true,
pageable: true,
detailInit: detailInit,
dataBound: function () {
    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
},
columns:
        [
            {field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "110px" },
            { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: "110px" },
            { field: "Country", width: "110px" },
            { field: "City", width: "110px" },
            { field: "Title" }
        ]});

function detailInit(e) {
  $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 5,
        filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.EmployeeID }
    },
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: false,
    selectable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns:
            [
                { field: "OrderID", width: "70px" },
                { field: "ShipCountry", title: "Ship Country", width: "110px" },
                { field: "ShipAddress", title: "Ship Address" },
                { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: "200px" }
            ]
  }).data("kendoGrid");
 }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the API of the Grid to expand it programatically.

```
//you can expand it programatically using the expandRow like this
element.on('click','tr',function(){
   $(element).data().kendoGrid.expandRow($(this));
})
```

Here is [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/WKSkC/3/) version.

Or you can use make the Grid selectable and use the select event instead of hooking a click event like shown above.

Comment: Actually,I'm trying to get the details grid in a separate div instead of inside the master grid. Is this possible?